# Fast look up if word exists in dictionary text file

Tags: c#, silverlight, performance, dictionary, lookup

I have a large text file (~10mb) that has more or less every dictionary in a specific language, and each word is new line deliminated.

I want to do a really fast lookup to see if a word exists in a file -
What is the fastest way to do this without looping through each line?

It is sorted, and I can do all the pre-processing I  want.

I considered doing some sort of Binary search, but I didnt know how I could do this, since all my lines are not a fixed number of bytes (and thus I wouldn't know where to jump the stream to). And surprisingly, I couldnt find a tool to do the fixed-width thing for me.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: I take it you can't just load the file into memory and keep it there?  10 MB isn't all that large . . .

Comment: If you *can* load the file into memory, then the generic `Dictionary` class will work.  Or, if you're using Silverlight 4, you can use `HashSet`.

Comment: Those are possibilities, sure, but what if I dont want to take the hit of the time it takes to load it all into memory? Also, this is a mobile device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest building a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) from the dictionary. That gives you very quick lookups to see whether a word is in there.

Comment: thats a possibility, but what if I dont want to take the hit of the time it takes to load it all into memory? Also, this is a mobile device.

Comment: @Steve: You said you can do all the preprocessing you wish. Have your requirements changed sometime in the last 30 minutes?

Comment: @Anon - no, it hasnt. I'm happy to preprocess it, but the question would then break down to:
1. If I do a trie, I have to load and create the datastructure into memory - this takes time, no? 
2. Similar to #1 - is doing #1 on each lookup faster than jumping around in a file? (I honestly dont know the answer, and thus looking for guidance)

Comment: @Steve: Why not store the trie on disk? Or keep it in memory rather than rebuilding it every time?

Comment: yes. if I did a trie, I would serialize and deserialize it to disk (although I dont know enough about a trie to do that). But keeping it around in memory isnt really as feasible - I need the app to start fast (and thus not incur the trie as part of the load time), and occasionally, once a user has acted, I would want to do the word lookup. I dont know enough about tries to really know how fast it would be to load it all either... =/

Comment: @Steve: You don't really need to load it at all - you can run it straight off disk with reasonable efficiency (especially as, being a mobile device, it probably has a good-for-random-access solid-state storage device instead of spinning metal).

Comment: wow, running it straight off the disk actually sounds appealing... can you please provide any further info on how I could do this? :)

Comment: @Steve: Sure. Give each node a unique number, referring to its position within the file - node 1 is the first node, node 2 is the second, etc.. Each node is the exact same size, and contains 26 integers, which refer to the next nodes. When it comes to lookups, open the root node, and read the value in the bucket corresponding to the first character. Compute the new offset into the file, open that node, and repeat until you get through the string or find a reference to 0, which means the string doesn't exist.

Comment: Happen to have any code sample anywhere? If not I'll try to read up on Tries a bit more tonight, since I dont understand them well enough, and maybe try to hack together a sample implementation

Comment: if you're on windows mobile? http://paratechnical.blogspot.com/2011/01/implementation-of-prefix-tree-data.html

Answer (score 1):

A trie is a good bet if you don't mind using some more storage: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie